# Unable to cast object of type in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to read my images from my MS Access database into my eigenobjectrecognizer. But now, I am getting an error which is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'Emgu.CV.Image`2[Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray,System.Byte]'.

I dont know what is this error is about. Below is my code.

```
int count = reader.FieldCount;

while (reader.Read())
{
    labels.Add(reader["FaceName"].ToString());
    trainingImages.Add((Image<Gray,byte>)reader["FaceImage"]);
}   
if (TSTable.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    ////    //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

    ////Eigen face recognizer
    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
        trainingImages.ToArray(), //database faceimage list
        labels.ToArray(), //facename list
        3000,
        ref termCrit);
```

Can someone help me with this. I am trying this for more than a week already but still I cant get any solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `reader["FaceImage"]` is the image file then you need to create a new image from the file:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(reader["FaceImage"]);
trainingImages.Add(image);
```

Comment: how can i find that pls?

Comment: @raaj5671 just debug it or you could try to print the value

Comment: well the value i tried to print out to the message box and it shows `System.Byte[]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line.

```
(Image<Gray,byte>)reader["FaceImage"]
```

The problem is that `reader["FaceImage"]` is of type `byte[]` and `Image<Gray,byte>`

1. Is not a base class of `byte[]`
2. Does not have an explicit nor implicit conversion operator from `byte[]`.

What you want is

```
{
    labels.Add(reader["FaceName"].ToString());
    byte[] buffer = (byte[]) reader["FaceImage"];
    Image<Gray,byte> image = new Image<Gray,byte>(buffer);
    trainingImages.Add(image);
}
```

Comment: but it says invalid arguments.[Here](http://screenshot.net/xd89gi1) is the screenshot of the error..

Comment: @raaj5671 Its not obvious what you are trying to do. A `byte[]` is about as generic as data gets. What is the `byte[]`. A bitmap, a jpeg, a gif?